# Generate new input field from date range value

Tags: javascript, html

i am in the process of making an HTML form when the users input the start Date and the end Date using the date range picker. after the users input the date, i want to generate new input field from the value of days from date range picker. for example : 2020-11-24 - 2020-11-27 = 3 days. so i want to generate 3 new input field.
Heres my code :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Generate new field from date range value</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Generate new input field from date range value</h1> <br> <br>
        Departure Date: <input id="departureDate" width="276" />
        Arrival Date: <input id="arrivalDate" width="276" />

        i want to generate new input field here
    </div>
    <script>
        var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());
        $('#departureDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: function () {
            return $('#arrivalDate').val();
        }
    });
    $('#arrivalDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
        minDate: function () {
            return $('#departureDate').val();
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can this be accomplished?
and sorry if my English is bad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?
You can use jquery append function. Read-more: https://api.jquery.com/append/

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Generate new field from date range value</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Generate new input field from date range value</h1> <br> <br>
        Departure Date: <input id="departureDate" width="276" onchange="handleChange(this)" />
        Arrival Date: <input id="arrivalDate" width="276" onchange="handleChange(this)"/>

        <div id="resultDate">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var dateSrc, dateTrg; 
        var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());
        $('#departureDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: function () {
            return $('#arrivalDate').val();
        }
    });
    $('#arrivalDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
        minDate: function () {
            return $('#departureDate').val();
        }
    });

    $('.new-dates').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
        minDate: function () {
            return $('#departureDate').val();
        }
    });

    function handleChange(ref) {
        if ($(ref).attr('id') === 'departureDate') {
            dateSrc = $(ref).val(); 
        } else {
            dateTrg = $(ref).val(); 
        }
        if (dateSrc && dateTrg) { 
            generateFields();
        }
    }

    function generateFields() {
        var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var range = Math.round(Math.abs((new Date(dateTrg) - new Date(dateSrc)) / oneDay));
        if (!$("#resultDate").is(':empty')) {
            $("#resultDate").html(''); 
        }
        if (range > 0) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < range ; i ++) {
                $("#resultDate").append('Result Date - ' + i + ': <input id="resultDate_' + i + '" width="276" onchange="doSomethingWithNewDate(this)"/>')
                $("#resultDate_" + i).datepicker({
                    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
                    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
                    format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    minDate: function () {
                        return $('#departureDate').val();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            $("#resultDate").html(''); 
        }
    }

    function doSomethingWithNewDate(ref) {
        
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```